# layered navigation block - place in product sort place prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to create a manufacturer (brand in my case) filter using the layered navigation block and place this next to my default sorting

in ps 1.5 i did this by inserting this code at my category.tpl

```
{include file="./modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.tpl"}
```

[image]

So now my problem is when i do this step at prestashop 1.6 i ecounter this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: nbr_filterBlocks in /home/vhost/dextertonstore2/cache/smarty/compile/2a/3d/27/2a3d274f79f30dbcf6a26fed74f871da2fb62e0e.file.blocklayered.tpl.php on line 44 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/vhost/dextertonstore2/cache/smarty/compile/2a/3d/27/2a3d274f79f30dbcf6a26fed74f871da2fb62e0e.file.blocklayered.tpl.php on line 44

Notice: Undefined index: nbr_filterBlocks in /home/vhost/dextertonstore2/cache/smarty/compile/2a/3d/27/2a3d274f79f30dbcf6a26fed74f871da2fb62e0e.file.blocklayered.tpl.php on line 436 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/vhost/dextertonstore2/cache/smarty/compile/2a/3d/27/2a3d274f79f30dbcf6a26fed74f871da2fb62e0e.file.blocklayered.tpl.php on line 436
```

i tried to clear the cache and recompile my template, i even deleted manually my cache in \cache\smarty\cache and \cache\smarty\compile but still im getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution here, this error occurs because there were no values that is pass on to our page.. in order to include the blocklayered.tpl to work .. what i did is i transplanted the layered nav into my left column and display it to none.. in this case .. the values are pass to our page by the blocklayered.php

Answer (score 0):

is `blocklayered.tpl` the same between the two installations (old and new)?

As I know, `./modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.tpl` is overriten after update. So maybe some of your changes are lost, especially regarding `nbr_filterBlocks` variable. You should do your changes inside of your theme folder (`my-theme/modules/blocklayered/blocklayered.tpl`).

Comment: no, i use the default layered nav in 1.6 while in 1.5 i use the old version.. im not tryng to modify the looks of my layered nav since i know how to modify it in the tpl.. i want to place the layered block next to the default sort that can be found in category.tpl , now my problem is to include the layered navs.tpl in hard coded way.. since the place of our default sort is not hookable .. the only way i think that i can insert the layered nav besides the default sort is by including the tpl .. this works in ps 1.5

Comment: But it seems your included tpl file contains a variable that is not sent by the current page controller. Do you agree with me? Please to check in your included tpl file if `nbr_filterBlocks` is mentionned anywhere and feedback to us.

Comment: yes i agree, i tried to remove the nbr_filterBlocks and this is the error i get

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: filters in /home/vhost/dextertonstore2/cache/smarty/compile/2a/3d/27/2a3d274f79f30dbcf6a26fed74f871da2fb62e0e.file.blocklayered.tpl.php on line 124 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/vhost/dextertonstore2/cache/smarty/compile/2a/3d/27/2a3d274f79f30dbcf6a26fed74f871da2fb62e0e.file.blocklayered.tpl.php on line 124